# Stop jQuery.css() function

Tags: jquery, css, function

Is there any way to stop jQuery css() function. I know that I can stop jQuery animate() function with jQuery.stop() function. But I don't know how to stop css() function. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "stop function"?

Comment: I mean, to stop $(selector).css({}) function like in animate() function before finishing the process.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: are you trying to stop css animations?

Comment: I assume you're referring to a CSS animation?

Comment: I have one span, I want to make it width 100% with jQuery.css function with transition. When I click the button, it will stop.

Comment: @PranavGupta yes I want to stop CSS function before it finishes its work.

Comment: Will the span go to 100% or stop at his current width?

Comment: the span will go for example to 48% and when I click the button it will stop in its last place in 48%.

Comment: Why not use `.animate` ?

Comment: @3rror404 because it makes problem with animate(). When I stop it, it stops normal, but when I click again to continue button, when it continues it makes delay for few milliseconds. I need accurate timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant actually do what you want with only class. But here what you can do :

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('span').width($('span').width());
})
```

Of course you'll need to adjust for your code. The goal here is to set the width to override the style sheet width on button click.

Comment: yes, it works! Thanks! But I have another problem which isn't related with this problem. When I stop animation and again click to continue button to set again css animation, it delays few milliseconds (seconds) before continuing.

Comment: I can't tell why since i cant see the code, but maybe your code take a lot of juice and that's why it is delayed...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop animating mid way you can do it buy storing the current width value when you click the `button` and applying the width to the `<span>`.

Please see my [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmtvf/) example.

**JQuery**

```
$('span').animate({'width': '100%'}, 5000)

$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    var width = $('span').width();

    $('span').stop(true, true).width(width);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Really nice example! ;-)